# When I try to save user record to db in node, only id is saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, saving-data

I have a problem with saving user's data to MongoDB; save function saves only user's id and also when I log user before trying to save it, I get only id too.
When I log req.body I get all the data.

I guess the problem is somewhere in instancing userSchema.

```
const userSchema = require('../models/user.model');
var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Here is my code:

```
module.exports.register = (req, res, next) => {
var user = new User(req.body);
user.name = req.body.name;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.username = req.body.username;
user.password = req.body.password;

user.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
        res.send(doc);
    }
    else {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.code == 11000) {
            res.status(422).send(['Duplicate email adrress found.']);
        }
        else
            return next(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is my console.log(req.body)

```
    {
      name: 'name',
      email: 'mail@mail',
      username: 'username123',
      password: '12345'
    }
```

And this is console.log('document' + doc)

```
document: { _id: 5ea3237a48b41b3cc08bfe1f, __v: 0 }
```

Comment: can you show your user schema

Comment: Sure, here it is:
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'This field can\'t be empty']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'This field can\'t be empty']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'This field can\'t be empty']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'This field can\'t be empty']
    },
    saltSecret: String
});

Comment: Please see the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue as you mention in the question is with the use model import

Can you add this at the end of the (user.model) model file: `module.exports = User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);` and import in controller as `const User = require("../models/user.model");`.

Just want to bring the attention to two different behavior of console log with "," and "+" . Please check it. And I don't think you need following 4 lines as well:

```
user.name = req.body.name;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.username = req.body.username;
user.password = req.body.password;
```

```js
let user = {"_id":"a", "name":"ABCD"};
  
console.log("doc"+ user)

console.log("doc", user)
```

Comment: With or without those 4 lines, when I log user all I get is this: 
{ _id: 5ea32b754c939026ec997f64 }

Comment: Can you check using any tool like MongoDB Compass to check the actual document in the DB?

Comment: Only id is saved to the database

Comment: Can you add this at the end of the (user.model) model file :=> module.exports = User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema); and import in controller as const User = require("../models/user.model");